# Remove URLs by domain from Firefox history and awesome bar

Tags: firefox, awesomebar

At my job, we recently move a lot of back-end services (e.g. ticket tracking, reporting, admin) from one server to another. Unfortunately, the way that our servers are configured, we're not using hostnames which can just move from one server to another.

So, in my Firefox history and awesome bar completion, I have a lot of references to one IP address (e.g. 111.111.111.111) and now they're all running on a different IP address (222.222.222.222).

Is there an easy way to delete all URLs which reference the old IP address?

(I'm not afraid to muck with the sqlite databases, but if there's an easier way, I'd like to hear)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bring up the *History* sidebar, select the undesired items, and remove them.

Comment: this also works on 'suggestions to fill out forms' (login fields).