# How to remove large number of entries from url history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, history

I want to remove large number of urls from my page history - they all match simple regexp, but there is a lot of them - doing this by "delete" in suggestion box is not an option. And when I bring history tab, whenever I click on item, it automatically opens - so I can't remove there anyway.

I heard that these urls are somewhere stored in sqllite format. Where exactly? Can I connect there and remove it from there (of course with Firefox **not** running)?

Comment: Similar question was here: http://superuser.com/questions/47999/remove-or-replace-urls-by-domain-from-firefox-history-and-awesome-bar/48002#48002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are right. In my Firefox profile directory, there is a filed named `places.sqlite`. Opening it with sqlite reveals (amongst others) the tables `moz_places` and `moz_historyvisits`. It seems that `moz_historyvisits` uses the primary of `moz_places` to refer to the URLs.

I suggest you back up that file before you start deleting.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, You **can do this from the Firefox history window** (opens with ***CTRL H***)

I presume that when you type "**regexp**" in the search pane, it shows all the entries you are interested in.

### First

- ***Right click*** on the first entry to
  select that item then press escape.
- The selected item will remain
  selected, but not opened.

### Then either

1. Hit ***CTRL A*** to select all the items, or
2. Hit ***Shift - DownArrow*** to select a subset of the selected entries

Then hit Delete

Comment: CTRL-H also works with the SeaMonkey Internet Suite (at least on Windows)

Comment: Firefox (at least since version 60) also offers a "Forget About This Site" context menu option when right-clicking on entries on the history sidebar. I believe this works via the hostname only, so be careful, since you might blow away all of Firefox's knowledge about an entire site you care about. But if it's what you want, it's one of the easier ways!

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in the `moz_places` table as full URL strings in the `places.sqlite` database, which is found in these locations:

> **Windows XP**
>
> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\[username]\Application
>   Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile
>   folder]\places.sqlite
>
> **Windows Vista**
>
> C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile
>   folder]\places.sqlite
>
> **GNU/Linux**
>
> /home/[user]/.mozilla/firefox/[profile
>   folder]/places.sqlite
>
> **Mac OS X**
>
> /Users/[user]/Library/Application
>   Support/Firefox/Profiles/default.lov/places.sqlite

of course, [user] and [profile folder] will be different for your machine.